# Get files in directory, print each by lines

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm porting some of my python scripts to Common Lisp. I need to get list of files in some directory and print each file's content by lines.
This code shows me all filenames. But lines are printed only for last file. Why?
Also, what is the best way ti iterate by file lines?
Thanks.

```
(dolist (file (directory (make-pathname :name :wild
                                        :type :wild
                                        :defaults "path\\to\\files\\")))
  (print file)
  (with-open-file (stream file)
    (do ((line (read-line stream) (read-line stream)))
        (nil t)
      (print line))))
```

Comment: I guess, it's the end-test-form, it's return nil.

Comment: NIL is always false. It loops forever. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to write a function which prints a file given a pathname and a stream.

You iterate with `DO`. That's okay, but I would use something like `LOOP` which allows slightly easier to read code.

Your `DO` is an endless loop. You might want to end the loop when the EOF is reached.

`READ-LINE` generates an error when it reads past the end of the file. Thus your code signals an error on the end of the first file. This error causes your code to only print the first file.

You need to call `READ-LINE` such a way that you test for EOF and end the iteration then. See the arguments to `READ-LINE`. Alternatively you can catch the EOF error, but the other solution is slightly easier.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
   (dolist (file (directory (make-pathname :name :wild
                                           :defaults "/tmp/lt/files/")))
     (print file)
     (with-open-file (stream file)
       (do ((line (read-line stream nil) (read-line stream nil)))
         ((null line))
         (print line))))
```